# C - Struct string elements are concatenated

Tags: c, string, struct

i have two string elements in my structure

```
struct mystruct{
    char mydate[10];
    char mytime[5];
};
```

They will store strings of type "XX:YY" and "XX-YY-ZZZZ" respectively.

But when I am assigning some value into these variables

```
struct mystruct *mystruct = (struct mystruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
strcpy(mystruct->mydate, "01-01-1970");
strcpy(mystruct->mytime, "00:01");
```

*mydate* variables is printing this:

```
01-01-197000:01
```

I am missing something? Can you help me? Thanks in andance!

- EDITED with more info
- don't works even if I increase the size by one

Comment: You didn't declare enough space for the trailing null byte.

Comment: Strings need length+1 to leave room for the terminator.

Comment: Use `mytime[6]` and `mydate[11]`.

Answer (score 4):

You have undefined behavior since there is not sufficient room in `mydate` to contain strings of the format "MM-DD-YYYY" - don't forget the implicit null terminator at the end.

What you're specifically observing is that the lack of the null terminator means that the output function (`puts`, `printf`, or whatever you're using) continues to read characters after the string ends. It so happens that there isn't any padding between `mydate` and `mytime` in your case, so the value in `mytime` appears to be part of the string as well.

Remember, since arrays decay to pointers when passed to functions, there is no way for a function with an array parameter to know when it is done reading the array; the null terminator acts as a sentinel value for this purpose.

Solution: Increase the size of both `mydate` and `mytime` to accommodate the null terminator as well.

Answer (score 1):

since you complained that your code did not work even with increased sizes, here is an example which works correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct mystruct1 {
    char mydate[11];
    char mytime[6];
};

void main() {
    struct mystruct1 *mystruct1 = (struct mystruct1*)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct1));

    strcpy(mystruct1->mydate, "01-01-1970");
    strcpy(mystruct1->mytime, "00:01");

    printf("date: %s, time: %s\n", mystruct1->mydate, mystruct1->mytime);
}
```

In this example every array has enough space to keep the string with the null terminator. So, you can compare it to your code.

In general it is also possible to keep sizes as in your example. But you need to always remember that the end of the string cannot be determined automatically and will require you to use specific function, like `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`. `printf` will not work directly as well. So here is another example:

```
struct mystruct2 {
    char mydate[10];
    char mytime[5];
};

void main() {
    struct mystruct2 *mystruct2 = (struct mystruct2*)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct2));

    strncpy(mystruct2->mydate, "02-02-2970", 10);
    strncpy(mystruct2->mytime, "00:02", 5);

    // need top prepare standard strings with terminator for printf
    char mydate[11]; // still need [11] for printf to work
    char mytime[6];

    strncpy(mydate, mystruct2->mydate, 10);
    mydate[10] = 0; // make sure to put a string terminator here
    strncpy(mytime, mystruct2->mytime, 10);
    mytime[5] = 0;

    printf("date: %s, time: %s\n", mydate, mytime);
}
```

The above makes sense in some situation where you are really tight on the memory, but should not be used in generic cases.

Comment: I would not recommend using `strncpy` as a "safe alternative" to `strcpy`; that is not its intended purpose

Answer (score 0):

The are at least two problems with the code.

1) You are writing too much in the `mydate` and `mytime`. The fix is either to allocate more memory in the struct, i.e., `char mydate[10+1];` & `char mytime[5+1];`. Or just don't write the `NULL` terminator. A solution for that, since you know the size in advance, use `memcpy(mystruct->mydate, "01-01-1970", sizeof(mystruct->mydate));` or similar `memcpy(mystruct->mytime, "00:01", 5);`.

2) The second part, print out, you are not showing (hint). So if you don't store the `NULL`-terminator then print out needs to be a little more delicate as shown in the example below.

```
// Possible dynamic max size
printf("date: %.*stime: %.*sThe\n",
       (int) sizeof(mystruct->mydate), mystruct->mydate,
       (int) sizeof(mystruct->mytime), mystruct->mytime);

// Fixed max size
printf("date: %.10stime: %.5sEnd\n",
       mystruct->mydate,
       mystruct->mytime);
```

Either way, the print out will be:

```
date: 01-01-1970time: 00:01The
date: 01-01-1970time: 00:01End
```

The `printf`-syntax used maximizes the length of the string printed.

BTW, your printout, `01-01-197000:01`, is likely the result of the compiler placing the memory layout of `struct mystruct` directly after each other in memory. The the resulting memory layout is equivalent to

```
struct mystruct {
    char my[15];
}
```

where the compiler knows that `mydate` starts at offset 0, and `mytime` starts at offset 10. This, if you filled your struct in the order of your example you first get `"01-01-1970\0"` followed by `"01-01-197000:01\0"` (where the last write is out of scope for the struct). So printing the date with `printf("%s", mystruct->mydate);` gives you your sequence output.

On the other hand, had you decided to write you data in the reverse order,

```
strcpy(mystruct->mytime, "00:01");
strcpy(mystruct->mydate, "01-01-1970");
```

the output of

```
printf("date: %s, time: %sEnd\n", mystruct->mydate, mystruct->mytime);
```

would be

```
date: 01-01-1970, time: End
```

since you time was overwritten my the null terminator of the `mydate` string copy.